# Problema con CSS en Spring Boot

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

tengo un pequeño problema en un proyecto (Spring Boot 3.1.2) que estoy haciendo: venia diseñando las vistas con Visual Studio (sin ejecutar el proyecto) y todo venia bien, pero cuando lo ejecutaba con el IDE (Intellij) no me tomaba el archivo CSS ni las imagenes.

[image: html sin tomar css]

Despues de googlear un poco, pasé todo eso a la carpeta static (antes estaban en "templates" junto a los html) y cambié la sintaxis en el head (th:href="@{/index.css}" en lugar de href="/static/index.css") y ahora funciona.

[image: html con css]

**Mis preguntas son:**

**1 - Aun sigue sin tomarme una parte del CSS, en la imagen que adjunto, los botones no son azules y tienen que estar más hacia la derecha de la pantalla. No sé cómo tengo que hacer.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2 - Por qué no me andaba con la sintaxis tradicional y tuve que poner esa otra? en las paginas que consulté no indicaban motivo. Hay alguna otra forma?**

Por si es necesario dejo captura del head. Desde ya gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo siempre en texto, nunca en imagenes.

Comment: Los atributos y etiquetas que empiezan por th:.. no son HTML, son templates de Thyme, una librería de plantillas que se suele usar con Spring